# What happens after steady-state forced oscillation when there's no force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

What happens when a steady-state forced oscillation stops being driven by a force? Does it inherit the frequency or it becomes a natural frequency? If the oscillation is damped, would it become the damped frequency?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it becomes the natural frequency.

After the force stops acting, the only forces acting on the system are the spring force and the damping force. When it leaves it has some velocity and some displacement from its mean position.

The only thing that changes is the amplitude which was constant in the forced oscillation.

Writing the forces you get $$\frac {md^2x}{dt^2}+b\frac {dx}{dt} +kx=0 $$

This is just your regular damped oscillation expression